# api gateway blocks CORS even when enabled

Tags: ajax, cors, aws-api-gateway

[image]

[image]

trying to call a simple `post` from my own domain by using jquery ajax

```
$.ajax({
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            url:  '/api/v1/tenants/all',
            data: {
                
            },
            success: function (res){
                console.log('success')
                console.log(res);
                drawPlacesOnMap(res.results)
                
            },
            error: function (res){
                console.log('error')
                console.log(res)
                alert(res.responseJSON.error)
            }
        });
```

getting blocked. the request does not reach the lambda application.
enabled CORS **and deployed**.

any ideas?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the issue was the `/` :-)

change `url` from `/api/v1/tenants/all` to `api/v1/tenants/all`